# How to bind c# object to WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am a deserializing a JSON object into C# and then equalling the datagrid ItemSource/DataContext to it. Auto generating columns works fine however I am only trying to get specific columns from the list and it does not appear to be working. I have also taken a look at the following answer but it does not appear to help me.
[WPF DataGrid binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789398/wpf-datagrid-binding-not-working)
Here is my code:

```
public class ARCGISapi
{
  [JsonProperty("locations")]
  public LocationElement[] Locations { get; set; }
}

public class LocationElement
{
  [JsonProperty("address")]
  public string Address { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("location")]
  public LocationLocation Location { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("score")]
  public long Score { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("attributes")]
  public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

private void PopulateGrid(string result)
{
  ARCGISapi apiWrapper = new ARCGISapi();
  apiWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ARCGISapi>(result);
  ResultsDataGrid.DataContext = apiWrapper.Locations;
  ResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = apiWrapper.Locations;
}

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" x:Name="ResultsDataGrid">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Binding="{Binding Score}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location.X}" />
 </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that an instance of `ARCGISapi` is set as the DataContext of your DataGrid (or Window), then the `ItemsSource` should be bound to `Locations` rather than `LocationElement` (the name of the property rather than the name of the type).

Comment: I have just changed it to "Locations" but unfortunately it still does not appear to be working.

Comment: The `DataContext` of the DataGrid and it's `ItemSource` can't be the same thing. If you're setting the ItemsSource manually, then you don't need to bind ItemsSource as well.

Answer (score 0):

In XML change this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding LocationElement}"
```

to this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
```